# Why ZeroDivide is resumable?

Tags: smalltalk

In Pharo (and other dialects) the `ZeroDivide` exception is resumable. Why?. For instance, if you evaluate `1 / 0` and then proceed, the answer is the `ZeroDivide` error. Why is this? Shouldn't `ZeroDivide` be not resumable?

**EDIT**:
Let's review this issue in more depth.

The problem here is that if the exception happens, what we get is the `ZeroDivide` exception. So, the only reason I can think of for making this exception resumable is to enable the following:

```
[a / b] on: ZeroDivide do: [:ex | ex resume: self anythingButTheQuotient],
```

right?

But this could have also be written

```
[a / b] on: ZeroDevide do: [self anythingButTheQuotient]
```

without requiring the exception to be resumable.

Resumable exceptions make sense if there is an "interesting" `#defaultAction`. But this seems not to be the case with `ZeroDivide`.

One could be tempted to say that in many cases one has this kind of code:

```
b = 0 ifTrue: [^0] ifFalse: [^a / b]
```

so why not using 0 as the `#defaultAction`? That would make the above code simpler (in those cases) and would only require a special handler in the (arguably) few ones that must behave differently. However, this would be a really bad decision because the default behavior would hide errors that, as we all know, the later they manifest the worst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is surprising at first sight, but the ANSI standard says:

> Zero divide exceptions are resumable so any message in this protocol
>   that signal such an exception may ultimately return to their sender.

The example you gave was trivial, but when installing the handler a few methods above, it's less trivial to resume the exception where it was signalled.

```
[self doSomethingComplex]
    on: ZeroDivide
    do:
        [:exception |
        "Handle zero divide as inf/nan as if performed in floating point arithmetic"
        exception resume: exception dividend asFloat / 0.0]
```

In Squeak or Pharo, see the references to `signalContext` instance variable in class `Exception`. You'll see that resuming is your sole option for returning control to the signaller.